# Passing data from UITableViewDataSource to UIViewController using protocol and delegate in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, delegates, protocols

I'm trying to pass data from a UITableViewDataSource to a UIViewController when a table row is selected. I think I'm pretty close.

**Protocol**

```
protocol BusDataDelegate {
    func didSelectRow(row: NSIndexPath, data: Route)
}
```

**Data Source**

```
class BusUITableView: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var busDataDelegate: BusDataDelegate?

    var routeService: RouteService = RouteService()

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        var busRoutes: [Route] = routeService.retrieve()
        return busRoutes.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell:BusUITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as BusUITableViewCell

        var busRoutes: [Route] = routeService.retrieve()

        cell.routeName.text = busRoutes[indexPath.row].name
        cell.routeNumber.text = busRoutes[indexPath.row].id
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        var busRoutes: [Route] = routeService.retrieve()

        busDataDelegate?.didSelectRow(indexPath, data: busRoutes[indexPath.row])
        println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

    }

}
```

**View Controller** - abbreviated

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, BusDataDelegate {

    func didSelectRow(row: NSIndexPath, data: Route) {
        println("Row: \(row) Data: \(data)")
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the problem is? You have just put the code without explaining the problem.

Comment: When the table view cell is tapped, I want to pass that data to the view controller. As for now I just want that didSelectRow function to be called, which should be able to access the data of the row is selected.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you only declared the `busDataDelegate` object, not assigned anything to it or not allocated it.

You are declaring it like:

```
var busDataDelegate: BusDataDelegate?
```

And using it like:

```
busDataDelegate?.didSelectRow(indexPath, data: busRoutes[indexPath.row])
```

But never assigned anything to that object or allocated it, that's the problem.

Comment: Can you tell me how to make the necessary changes?

Comment: @RobertHirsch: From where you are showing the `ViewController` and `BusUITableView` ?